# HTML with event.preventDefault

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, ios4

If the html document is disabled. (no scrolling...)

```
document.ontouchmove = function(event){ event.preventDefault(); }
```

Can I selectively enabled elements in the html document? such as a div, span
What javascript should I use to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here’s a fairly hacky solution.

Change your `touchmove` handler as follows:

```
document.ontouchmove = function (event) {
    if (!event.elementIsEnabled) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
};
```

Then for an element that you want to enable:

```
element.ontouchmove = function (event) {
    event.elementIsEnabled = true;
};
```

This works because:

- When a `touchmove` event is fired on the element, both of these event handlers handle the event in the bubbling phase. This means that the element `touchmove` handler fires first, because it is closest to the source of the event.
- When two event handlers handle the same event, they receive the same event object.
- You’re allowed to set your own arbitrary properties on an event object.

So, the element `touchmove` handler just sets a custom property on the event object, and then the document `touchmove` handler checks for that custom property to determine whether the default action should be prevented.

Comment: Is there a way to scroll within an element not the entire page. I tried setting a div height:100px; overflow:scroll; in CSS but it didn't work. (the actual height of the div is 500px).

Comment: The iPhone deliberately does not support `overflow: scroll`, because Apple think it creates usability issues on a mobile device. Depending on what you’re trying to do, perhaps this will help you: http://cubiq.org/scrolling-div-on-iphone-ipod-touch

Comment: This works amazingly. I've seen all kinds of people comment about this subject but I've never seen anything work as well your solution. Thank you!