# how to reverse e.preventDefault() from the body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, drag

I have this:

```
function dontMove(event) {
    // Prevent page from elastic scrolling
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

&

```
<body ontouchmove="dontMove(event);">
```

This, on the ipad, stops it from being draggable and does not allow that grey background the ipad has when you drag a whole page around to show up.

I have seen on another website that its possible to reverse that in another div, so that div is completely draggable again.

Does anyone know how to reverse it?

I have also tried using this to prevent it (in the document.ready):

```
document.ontouchmove = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

& this to enable it:

```
function doTouchMove(state) {
    document.ontouchmove = function(e){
    return state;
    }
}
```

Then I put this to activate it.

```
<img ontouchmove="doTouchMove(state);" src="../jpeg/pages/01.jpg" class="touch"/>
```

This didn't seem to work
Is there anything wrong with this?
Or any other way that might work?

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly why `bubbles` is slightly better(at least in my opinion).

`bubbles` is cross browser, so you should be able to replace.

```
e.preventDefault()
```

with

```
e.bubbles = false;
```

and then latter in your code, you could potentially reset `bubbles` to `true`.

If the above isn't an option then just ignore.  :D

An alternative(if you are just working with an iPad) is to just reverse how the DOM works.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(){}, true );
```

This will force the event to work in the other direction.

```
Document click execute
                     |
                     |
                     v
                  Element click execute
```

Answer (score 0):

try this post, [HTML with event.preventDefault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508540/html-with-event-preventdefault) and erase **ontouchmove** from body tag.

Mine looks like this

```
<script>
    // Get touch move enevt from IOS
    document.ontouchmove = function (event) {
        if (!event.elementIsEnabled)
            event.preventDefault();
    };

    // Get touch move enevt from IOS
    function enableOnTouchMove(event) {
      event.elementIsEnabled = true;
    };
</script>
```

then enable ontouchmove on every tag you want. ie:

```
<div ontouchmove="enableOnTouchMove(event)" id="listing">
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it with

```
$('#form1').unbind('submit').submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by preventing the event only if it comes from the body:

```
document.ontouchmove = function(event){
  if(event.target.tagName == "BODY"){
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```